# How to configure arrayfire-rust to use CUDA?

Tags: rust, arrayfire

I've installed the latest official CUDA (7.5) and  ArrayFire (Linux v3.3.1 64-bit) on Ubuntu 15.10.  I am using the default configuration following the official documentation.

When I build the [arrayfire-rust library](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire-rust) and run the "unified" example in the ./examples folder, it shows me I only have CPU and OpenCL backends. The CUDA backend can not be found.

How do I configure the wrapper to support CUDA?

The official C++ examples can be built successfully using CUDA.

---

**Another question**

How to modify the `build.conf` file to build the `arrayfire` submodule available in the Rust wrapper? When I git clone the source from GitHub.

How can I config these options:

```
"glew_static": "OFF",
"freeimage_type": "DYNAMIC",
"cpu_fft_type": "FFTW",
"cpu_blas_type": "LAPACKE",
"cpu_lapack_type": "LAPACKE",

"freeimage_dir": "E:\\Libraries\\FreeImage\\Dist",
"fftw_dir": "E:\\Libraries\\fftw-3.3.4",
"acml_dir": "",
"mkl_dir": "",
"lapacke_dir": "E:\\Libraries\\lapack",
"glew_dir": "E:\\Libraries\\GLEW",
"glfw_dir": "E:\\Libraries\\glfw3",
"boost_dir": "E:\\Libraries\\boost_1_56_0",

"cuda_sdk": "/usr/local/cuda",
"opencl_sdk": "/usr"
```

I checked the path of CUDA libs and the `cuda_sdk` option seems correct. In addition, `$AF_PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` have been set. What's the problem with my config?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the Stack Overflow guidelines; it's not a forum and should be treated differently! For example, please ask only [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).